# Help with discrete math proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm having trouble with the following:

$\ a_1=1$ and $a_n=1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i$ for $n>1$

How should I go about proving the below? Any hints?

$a_n = 2^{n-1}$

Comment: Did you try induction?

Comment: That's what I was thinking at first. I started off by breaking up the summation, but that got me into a loop. I'm not entierly sure where to start off.

Answer (score 2):

Induction is the obvious choice in these kinds of problems.

1. For $n=1$, the statement is obviously true.
2. Now, we should prove the statement for $n+1$ by assuming it is true for all values $k\leq n$. That is, we know that $a_k = 2^{k-1}$ for all values $k\leq n$. Then, we have $$a_{n+1} =1 + \sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^n 2^{i-1}$$
   Can you now prove that $a_{n+1} = 2^n$?

Answer (score 2):

Induction is ugly xd

$$
a_n-a_{n-1}=\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i\right)-\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}a_i\right)=a_{n-1}
$$
Considering that $a_1=2^0$ then $a_n=2^{n-1}$.

Comment: You've shown that $a_n=2a_{n-1}$. An induction is used, if a simple one, to show that $a_n=2^{n-1}$.

Comment: I would bet someone was going to point out this xd

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can prove it by induction. Note that $\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{i-1} =2^n-1$